# linux cp current directory level only

Tags: bash, cp

I have a dir that contains files and subdirs. I want to copy files in the dirs only, so I run

```
cp -v src/* dst/
```

and get error `cp: -r not specified; omitting directory`. I'd be ok to ignore it but the command fails if the `-e` bash flag is set.

How can I avoid my script failure assuming I do NOT want to copy recursively and I do want `-e` flag? The only thing I can think about is to use `find -type f -maxdepth... -exec cp...`  but it looks too heavy. Any simpler way?

p.s. I know about `-e` bottom rocks, thanks.

Comment: Does appending `|| true` to the command eliminate the failure when `-e` is set?

Comment: This is the best solution so far. Please move it from comment to answer and I'll accept it. @doneal24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common technique to have `-e` set in your script but still have commands that you know can produce errors is to make them part of a conditional command, e.g.

```
cp -v src/* dst/ || true
```

This construct will never produce an error that would cause the script to exit. No fancy programming required and it is applicable to many commands, not just to the `cp` example.

Answer (score 1):

With "extended glob" (shopt -s extglob) enabled, use `src/!(*/)` to match all items *except* those which would match `src/*/` (directories or symlinks to directories).

Another common way to copy specific files is `cpio -p`, `find src/ [...] | cpio -p dst/`.